# Least squares method: must each partial derivative be zero?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

In gradient equations, does the sum of the partial derivatives have to be equal to zero or each derivatives has to be zero?

As I have just started to understand gradient equations, if my question is not explaining well, please let me know.

Comment: Better start at the beginning, and tell us what you mean by "gradient equations".

Comment: I was reading wikipedia to understand how to estimate parameters for a linear equation. Wikipedia show the method called " Least Square Method" to estimate parameters, and it uses gradient equations using partial derivatives. I kind of understand partial derivatives but I am kind of having trouble in understand gradient euqation.

Comment: So is there a link where we can see the definition, or the use, of gradient equations? Wikipedia is a big place, you know.

Comment: Hope this can take you there: Solving the lest squares problem part at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares

Answer (score 1):

The question is not entirely clear. In the notation at the link in the comments, each partial derivative $\partial S\over\partial\beta_j$ has to be zero. But each partial derivative is expressed as a sum (well, a linear combination) of other partial derivatives, $${\partial S\over\partial\beta_j}=2\sum_ir_i{\partial r_i\over\partial\beta_j}$$ and it's just the sum on the right that has to be zero (for each $j$), not the individual derivatives ${\partial r_i\over\partial\beta_j}$.